# jQuery selector for matching at start AND end of ID?

Tags: jquery

I have a group of buttons on my web page which all have an id that end with the text "EditMode".

I'm using jQuery to assign an event to like so

```
$('[id $=EditMode]').click(editHandler);
```

However now I want to prefix the id with a name (which I will know in advance) so the id would be "aName+someotherstuff+EditMode". How do I alter the above expression so I match on aName AS WELL as editMode?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

```
$('[id ^=aName][id $=EditMode]')
```

Comment: I would always just add quotes around your selector name like so
`$('[id ^="aName"][id $="EditMode"]')`
See fiddle for working example https://jsfiddle.net/u6mzs720/

Comment: This works great for filling ASP BeginCollection elements via javascript.

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, you can use the "add()" function for readability, but I would recommend Chaos's method:

```
$("[id ^=aName]").add("[id $=EditMode]")
```

Comment: Actually this answer does not achieve the same as chaos answer. This selects all elements with id's beginning with 'aName' and all id's ending with 'EditMode'. Chaos' answer would select all elements that both begin 'aName' and end 'EditMode' within each id. I used this 'for readability', before realising my mistake, as I was selecting input fields and the square braces are a little confusing. If it helps any one else that is written like: `$("input[name^='start_term']input[name$='[end_term]']")`