# jQuery - select all inputs with array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a lot of input fields like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="participants[1][canceled]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="participants[2][canceled]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="participants[3][canceled]">
```

I am looking for a jQuery selector that gives me all of these items. I dont want to use a loop. I would prefer something like:

```
jQuery('[name="participants[*][canceled]"]') // actually dont work
```

Is that possible?

Thank you

**EDIT: Thanks to all of you**

```
$(':hidden[name^="participants["][name$="][canceled]"]');
```

Was my solution and works like a charm. Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise this is the correct way:

```
$(':hidden[name^="participants["][name$="][canceled]"]');
```

Or if you need to match numbers only:

```
$(':hidden').filter(function() {
    return /^participants\[\d+\]\[canceled\]$/.test(this.name);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qbgAL/

Comment: This one is a nice idea.. I like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) in your context,

```
jQuery('[name^="participants"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the array `name` then you can just use `participants`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/9bH5a/)**

```
jQuery('[name*=participants]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like `$("input:hidden[name^='participants']")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142644/jquery-selector-for-matching-at-start-and-end-of-id)

```
$('[name ="participants"][name $="[canceled]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('[name^="participants"][name$="[canceled]"]')
```