# jquery - select dom by name like

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a lot of doms with these names:

```
<input id="partido1-jugada4-empate" name="bets[3][0][0]" title="partido1-jugada4-empate" type="radio" value="X">

<input id="partido1-jugada4-empate" name="bets[3][1][0]" title="partido1-jugada4-empate" type="radio" value="X">
```

...

```
<input id="partido1-jugada4-empate" name="bets[3][13][0]" title="partido1-jugada4-empate" type="radio" value="X">
```

I need select these with something like:

```
$( "input[name*='[3][*][0]']" )
```

where previous line give some input with that name

Comment: You can't use wildcards in the middle of the class like that, but you could concatenate a variable in there if your JavaScript knows what number is supposed to go there, maybe in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this question here suggests

[jQuery selector for matching at start AND end of ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142644/jquery-selector-for-matching-at-start-and-end-of-id)

You should do the following:

```
$("input[name ^=//[13//]][name $=//[0//]")
```

So it reads if the name starts with [13] and ends with [0]

The backslashes '//' are used to tell jQuery that '[' and ']' are not it's reserved brackets.

Edit:

The proper answer is thanks to:

[ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385672/%E1%BE%A0%E1%BF%97%E1%B5%B2%E1%84%90%E1%B6%8C)

In the comments below :)

Comment: Nice answer - Some reason I had a mind block on how to structure it just using a selector

Comment: hi thanks for answer... but I'm obtaining an error with syntax expression

Comment: @DanielGarciaSanchez the correct selector syntax is `$('input[name^="bets[3]["][name$="][0]"]')`

Comment: thanks @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ it's very very awesome, it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) and use a regex to compare the name to see if it matches a certain pattern

```
var x = $('input').filter(function(i,v){
    return /^bets\[3\]\[.+\]\[0\]$/.test(v.name);   
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex0r3d7q/)

```
^bets\[3\]\[.+\]\[0\]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pysYpn2E4fANW6hP)